# How to make "checked" on md-radio-button in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to check an `md-radio` button. I saw on their website that they do it in scope in `app.js` but need to do it dynamically. I have tried with `ng-checked` but didn't work.

Is there any way to modify the javascript variable `data` of `$scope` to add the checked?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: That means that at runtime is that I know that must be "checked".

Comment: The problem is that the "ng-model" and the element that will be "checked" I not previously know, depends on multiple queries to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Init your controller's scope variable to the value you have in your `md-radio-button` defined.

In Controller:

```
$scope.gender = 'male';
```

In template:

```
<md-radio-button ng-model="gender" value="male">Male</md-radio-button>
```

Here male will be selected.
You can change it even on some actions (click, ajax load, etc..), you just need to change the model value to the right value in order to have it selected.

Comment: The problem is that the "ng-model" and the element that will be "checked" I not previously know, depends on multiple queries to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you need to load it from DB, try it, on you promise:

```
promise.then( function (response) {
   $scope.yourVarHere = response.data.yourValueFromServer;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

`ng-checked` is used to check only for checkbox type button to be used with 
 either-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male" ng-checked="male"> Male
```

or

```
<md-checkbox value="male" ng-checked="male" aria-label="male"> Male </md-checkbox>
```

If you want to check a radio button as  `md-radio-button`  use  `ng-value`  instead of  `value`  without  `ng-checked="male"`  E.g.

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="gender">
    <md-radio-button ng-value="male" >mlae </md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button ng-value="female" >female </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

this code segment will model values of **gender** and **male** will be checked if previously **gender = 'male'**.

Hope this will help!